# MindTap by Cengage Learning "HTML/ CSS" Texbook GitHub integration

Tags: html, github

This is my first official Stack Overflow question, because I am really STUCK! I can't seem to push my source code to my remote GitHub repository.

[image: screen shot of terminal commands not working]

What am I missing!?!?!

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We don't really work from screen shots around these parts.

Comment: But the instructions are there in the hint block: You need to pull before you can push.

Comment: haha! no screen shots next time. the instructions in my textbook dont mention push but I felt that I was missing something .....

Answer (score 0):

You can override any checks that git does by using "force push". Use this command in terminal

```
git push -f origin master
```

However, you will potentially ignore the existing work that is in remote - you are effectively rewriting the remote's history to be exactly like your local copy.